# How do I remove 'untitled' partition from terminal or disk utility?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, catalina

I've been trying for ages but can't work out how to completely remove these two Untitled volumes(?). I've tried remove, erase, and the minus button in Disk Utility and the commands in terminal don’t make sense or seem to work .  Please find attached images. I have Catalina OS

[image: disk utility screenshot]

[image: list from disk utility]

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Nothing on disk3 needs changing yet, so all the CS commands are dangerous or ineffective

What happens when you issue:

```
diskutil eraseVolume free free disk0s4
diskutil eraseVolume free free disk0s3
```

Also, please use care, if you delete the wrong 0s4 you will lose everything. Do you have a backup and internet to reinstall if you or I make a mistake?

Comment: Hi thank you for replying so promptly <3, do i run all those in one go or do each one individually?

Comment: David Anderson that worked a charm thank you so much i could kiss you

Comment: Either of you feel free to edit my post or put up what worked in a proper answer. Main goal is to get a check on the correct answer in the end.

Comment: I will keep that in mind next time. Deleting previous comments.

Comment: Thank you again, I feel like you did the heavy lifting here @DavidAnderson